# Can the Tailed Beasts' relative power levels be compared?

Tags: naruto

A Tailed Beast's power seems to be greater the more tails it has. For example:

- Power of 3-Tailed Beast = Power of 2-Tails + 1-Tails.
- Power of 9-Tailed Beast = Power of 8-Tails + 7-Tails + ... + 1-Tails.

This is clear. But is it possible to compare the power level of the 1-Tails and 2-Tails with this equation? Does the power of the 2-Tailed Beast = the power of the 1-Tailed one? Or is it greater?

Reference links:

1. Most of them have shared the same idea in [this link](http://mangahelpers.com/forum/showthread.php/62931-8-Tailed-vs-9-Tailed-beast-Chakra-lvl-%28or-Kuubi-vs-hachibi%29-at-current-state).
2. Badranious's answer in [this thread](http://narutobase.net/forums/showthread.php?t=187065).

Comment: The fact is that tails do not decide the power of a particular bijuu, it's been proven by manga. The fact is simple: any of the bijuu can buttkick Kurama including Shukaku, and Kurama can also kick their asses. Depends on who is smarter and who uses their right power at the right time...

Comment: Yea there really isn't a "power lvl equation" for comparing the tailed beasts, the more the tails, the larger the chakra..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, it's never explicitly said that *every* Bijuu is stronger than *all* of the Bijuu with lesser tail number **combined**.

The practical power probably *is* determined by tail number (even though the Eight Tails told the Nine Tails that it isn't, much like 'friendship' is more valued than 'power').

It **is** stated that the Nine Tails is stronger than all of the rest combined, because Itachi said that if it were to be sealed anytime but last, the Gedo Mazo won't be able to withstand the imbalance, and will break apart.

---

There isn't a clear power distribution and balance, nothing is explicitly stated, so most of what you'll hear is speculation.

As for the specific question, I'd say that the Two Tails is "just stronger" than the One Tail.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, in chapter 567, page 10, the Hachibi tells the Kyuubi that

> Strength isn't determined by the number of tails one has.

[image]
*(this is a part of page 10)*

Although the Kyuubi does think that the number of tails equals power, which is a reason for the friction between te Bijuu (this is also stated in [the Naruto Wiki page on Bijuu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tailed_Beasts#History)).

Still, this was the only time when this was said. If the number of tails really does not determine the power one Bijuu has, there has been no other explanation for the relation between the power of the Bijuus.

Comment: That's like saying "A shinobi's power isn't determined by Chakra, but by the power of his 'love and friendship'". In reality, I'd kick nearly anyone's ass, and their friendship too.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Fair enough. But do we know that the Hachibi meant it like that?

Comment: We don't know for sure. But I believe that he means that when working in collaboration with Humans, like the SOSP intended them to, they can reach higher levels of power, even without having more tails.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison of tailed-beast power levels has not been explicitly stated in manga or anime. But following things have been mentioned in the manga:

1. 10-Tails is the origin of all of the chakra.
2. 9-Tails is stronger than all other beasts combined (Of course, not counting 10-Tails).
3. 9-Tails, with only half of its total strength, was able to counter 5 other tailed-beasts.

Based on those three observations, I have a theory that seems to fit in fairly well with manga.

Since tailed-beasts aren't the only beings with chakra, it is safe to assume that 10-Tails has more chakra than all the other tailed-beasts combined. Also, Hagoromo created 1 to 9-Tails by dividing 10-Tails chakra, and he made 9-Tails stronger than other tailed-beasts. He must have followed the same pattern for all the tailed beasts unless he randomly chose to make 9-Tails overpowered, which seems very unlikely. So, that leads to my assumption that 8-Tails must be having more chakra than the combined chakra of all tailed-beasts having lesser tails than 8-Tails, and so on.

Now, using the following classic geometric series:

Let the amount of chakra of a tailed-beast be denoted by 'x / [2<sup>10-n</sup>]'; where x is all of the chakras, and n is the number of tails of the particular tailed-beast.

Based on that formula:

- 10-Tails has 'x' amount of chakra, which is all of the chakras and is consistent with observation (1).
- 9-Tails has 'x/2' amount of chakra, 8-Tails has 'x/4', and so on. This way, each tailed beast will have slightly more chakra than the combined chakra of all tailed-beasts with lesser tails. And that is consistent with observation (2).
- Also, according to the formula, 1 to 7-Tails' combined chakra would be less than half of 9-Tails' total chakra, and that explains observation (3).

Comment: how is this relevant to the question ? you are just saying 9 tails is greater or not even that. Can the relative power levels of all the tailed beasts be compared is what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to say that in the anime, in set 16, when Killer B took on Kisame, B only sprouts 6 chakra tails, and when Kisame won a small taijutsu contest, he sprouted 2 more tails, Kisame that B was taking him seriously.

Also if the tails are of chakra, then how could one have just as much chakra as 9-Tails? It could be that maybe 1-Tail is more concentrated than 9-Tails.

Also, before Shippuden, when Naruto would get more tails in the cloak, the higher the power. Also, the 9-Tails chakra cloak does damage to the environment, but the 1-Tail (according to the forums) does not.

Also, when Naruto goes into the 9-Tails chakra cloak, at 4-Tails it starts damaging him, but the 8-Tails chakra cloak does not do damage until all 8 are out (some of the info is from wiki so may or not be correct.

Also, another thing is that when Kisame would use Samehada to rip out B's chakra, the number of tails went down showing that there is a correlation in the number of the tails. Although most of this is speculation, if you look close, it seems like there are lots of small (and huge) hints.

For sure, there seem to be quite a few hints display but it is nowhere said outright that more tails = more power. By adding clues we can only assume but with all the clues given to us, we're probably right anyway.

Comment: This is a three-year old question with an accepted answer. There's no rush, so take your time, fix your errors, explain your logic, and find which chapter/episode the events you're talking about happened in.