# Is the Nine Tails still stronger than the Eight Tails even though half of him was sealed away?

Tags: naruto

I've not read the manga series, so the question may be quite basic.

In an earlier discussion, it was said that the number of tails determines the power of the tailed beast. Since half the Nine-tail's chakra was sealed by the Fourth Hokage, does it mean that the Eight-tails now has more chakra than the Nine-tails?

Comment: I find it pretty stupid how strong kurama actually is. I mean really, why would it make sense that the nine tails can match if not surpass five tailed beast balls.. makes no sense. I just don't like the fact that there's that much of a power difference. Kinda makes all the tailed beast seems useless at this point.

Comment: The Nine Tailed fox is Still Stronger Than All Other Beasts (Even Though It Is Half Of Its Power

Answer (score 6):

It's not specified explicitly, but I think not.

Itachi told Kisame that the nine-tails had to be sealed last, **because if it doesn't, the Gedo Mazo would be thrown out of balance, and break down**. Akatsuki definitely knew about how the Kyuubi was sealed, because Tobi was there.

> In the manga, Naruto together with the Nine Tails managed to fire a bijuudama of equal scale to that of the Two, Three, Four, Five, Six and Seven tails combined.

From those I conclude that even after half of him was sealed away, the Nine Tails *still* has more power than the rest of the tailed beasts, if not combined!

Comment: Tobi wasn't there when the Kyuubi was sealed. He retreated after Minato defeated him. ([Chapter 503, page 6](http://www.mangapanda.com/93-55672-8/naruto/chapter-503.html))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is it possible that the Kyuubi's chakra was getting replenished?

Comment: @ChetterHummin: Not likely, though possible. I'm saying it's not likely, because up until now, when the Nine-tails used his chakra in the manga, it was pure Yang.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any evidence, but I always thought that each Tailed Beast was exponentially stronger than the previous.  Something like 10x 1-tails = 1x 2-tail.

If anyone has evidence of this, edit it in the answer.

According to the questipon [provided by JNat](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/1940/tailed-beast-power-equation)
The equation could be like this:   (x)t = beast w/ # of tails
(Addition)

```
1t + 1t = 2t

1t+ 2(1t) = 3t

1t + 3(1t) + = 4t

...

1t + 8(1t) = 8t

1t + 9(1t) = 9t
```

**9t/2 < 8t**

In which case the 1/2 of Nine Tails wouldn't be stronger than the 8 tails.
If it were like this, then the equation could be more like:

```
8! (8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1) = 8 tails

9! (9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1) = 9 tails
```

**9t/2 > 8t**

or it can be

```
8t = 7t + 6t + 5t ...

9t = 8t^x
```

**9t/2 > 8t**

x being the number of times stronger in which each tailed beast is stronger than the other.

**This all depends on whether the tailed beasts are exponentially stronger than another or additionally strong**

Comment: Yes, but the concern of the question is regarding the sealing of half of the Nine-tails' chakra. After said sealing, is that formula still valid?

Comment: well yea, say 9-tails is 10x stronger than the 8 tails.  With only half being sealed.  Hes now only 5x stronger.

Comment: Ok, seems fine. Also, see [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/1940/tailed-beast-power-equation), for discussion on Tailed Beasts' power equation.

Comment: @JNat There isn't any definite equation, but if each tail beast was exponentially stronger.  Then the power of the Kyubii can be stronger than all combined.

Comment: And another thing, the 8 tails lost a tail during the fight with sasuke so he lost 1/8 of his power.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure if it works like that. And [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gy%C5%ABki) it is stated the the tails grow back, and that the Third Raikage once cut off all of his (the eight tails) tails. But it does not state references for those statements.

Comment: Well that would mean that the 9-Tails could infact regenerate the lost chakara from the seal similar to people using jutsu.

Comment: Not necessarily. Because losing a tail might not mean losing power. I think!

Comment: I don't think this math applies. For all we know, The sage wanted to divide the Juubi's chakra, but has underestimated it. It resulted in the nine-tails being 10 times more powerful than the rest combined. **We don't know that much!**, all we know is that the Nine-tails is so powerful that unless the Mazo *already has* all other eight sealed, sealing the Nine-tails will result in the Mazo not being able to sustain the imbalance and break apart.

Answer (score 1):

The eight tails can regenerate its lost limbs remember? But that regeneration does not apply to his horn that the raikage has cut. So that means the eight tails didnt lose 1/8 of its chakra. And also according to the manga when sasuke revived orochimaru, they took one of the uzumaki clans masks and orochimaru released the reaper death seal so that he can reanimate the previous 4 hokage. And since Minato used this jutsu to seal half of the nine tails, then the moment orochimaru released the technique is also the time when the nine tails power is restored. But since the power of the tailed beasts is measured by the number of their tails I could say that the eight tails is stronger than the nine tails if orochimaru did not release the technique but since he did then the nine tails is much stronger. But remember what I am saying is according to the manga. We do not know which story is going to be used either the story of the manga or the story of naruto shippuden ultimate ninja storm 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think Kurama is much stronger. Having half of his chakra taken away and a bit from naruto he was still able to form a tailed beast ball powerful enough to match the other tails collaborated tail beast ball. 8 tails would have had no chance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered it was his physical form that was not sealed, which is probably why in the anime his beast transformation is so different than Bees.  Just chakara, no physical form to stand on.

Answer (score 0):

Its because its matched with narutos stength he's by him self stronger then the 8 tails host so match that up with the rest of the nine tails and he's just epic

Answer (score -2):

Kurama is stronger then all the other tailed beasts.
According to what Kurama says their power is determined by how many tails they have. With that he is implying that he is the strongest (which he is) and saying the one tailed Shukaku is the weakest of the 9 beasts.
That's why he hates Kurama.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to say?

Comment: Please consider clarifying your answer. Right now, it's impossible to understand what you're trying to say. As it is now, your answer will be downvoted, and even possibly deleted! Please try to improve it. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the link.

Comment: @senshin i understand it, the answer is indicating that the more tails a Tailed Beast has the stronger it is. Shukaku being the 1-Tailed Beat is the weakest and hates Kumara the 9-Tailed Beast (i haven't seen enough of Naruto to confirm that name) for having the most number of tails. similar to what [Kohakuren](http://eushully.wikia.com/wiki/God_Catching_Alchemy_Meister:Characters#Kohakuren_.2F_.E5.A6.96.E7.8B.90.E3.82.B3.E3.83.8F.E3.82.AF.E3.83.AC.E3.83.B3) says in Kamidori when describing her tails (it takes 150 years of experience to develop a single tail so she's lived for 1200+ years)