# Why does Konoha have only 1 tailed beast?

Tags: naruto

While others have 2 considering 1st hokage distributed it to other villages.

It doesn't make sense to give other villages to have advantage of having more power. I haven't read manga so have no clue if it's been addressed somewhere.

Comment: 9 tails + 8 tails can fight the other tailed beast. just sayin'.:) Isn't that imbalance if they have at least 2 tailed beast?

Comment: Again probably not. Each tailed beast would be equally powerful (my assumption).

Comment: Rather than instruct the world who's the strongest by hoarding the beasts, the First divvied out these nukes to show trust and encourage others to trust him. Besides, how threatening can two beasts be to the guy who was in charge of handing them out?

Comment: Idt it was mentioned but they had 2. Rin was the 3 tails jinchuruki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Their power levels are not equal. Nine-tails power level is equal to every other tailed beast **combined**. It is stated in no plainer words. However, a beast's power is not determined by the number of tails it has, e.g. two- through eight-tails have a comparable power level.

[Check this out for more info.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/1943)

Comment: Why would you say that Shukaku is stronger than either Matatabi or Son Goku?

Comment: You're right. After looking into it, that was a presumptuous statement to make.

Answer (score 6):

Adding on to what omni said:

The first Hokage wished/hoped for peace among the five countries, not use their power for war. During the first meeting of the Kages, Hashirama even bowed his head, asking for understanding and peace. To show his sincerity, he might have given the other villages one more tailed-beast than his own.

It's true that Kurama is the strongest among all the tailed-beasts, but I am unsure whether  or not Kurama can take on two of the other tailed-beasts by himself.

Answer (score 0):

Dudes look at it this way the yondaime split the kyuubi into two halves reducing its max output and size and yet it can still beat the hell out of the others of all the beast it has the most chakra even when split in half to show how awesome it is . oh and the higher the tail the more powerful the beast  chakra sensors know this fact people like Karin and the blonde body gaurd the 4th raikage brought with him

Answer (score 0):

Kurama inspires utter terror in every living thing, even most of the other Tailed Beasts. If say Matatabi was unleashed on the battlefield by Cloud and the Leaf answered by unleashing Kurama, Matatabi would probably run like hell in the opposite direction to Kurama with her tails between her legs. Gyuki might've stayed to fight but any other Tailed Beast, maybe except Shukaku (because he's a crazy son of a raccoon) would duck right on out of there.

I'd say Kurama is so powerful that the threat he represents is so great that Hashirama didn't feel the need to keep another Tailed Beast. Add to that the Leaf having the Uzumaki Clan, who could release and reseal Kurama practically at will and Hashirama himself, who could apparently 1 vs 1 every single Tailed Beast and come out on top, every other village wouldn't have dared to use their Tailed Beasts against them.

Answer (score -1):

When Hashirama convened the first Kage summit to distribute the tailed beast, he wanted to distribute them to each village based on power. Three of the four great nations and received 2 tailed beast while sunagakure already possessed the 1 tail and did not desire another, so takigakure took possession of the 7 tails for their commemorative strength of not being one of the great nations. Since the nintails possessed chakra comparable to equivalently 5 tailed, the first hokage sall acquirring another tailed beast would disrupt the balance of power between nations and thus settled with having the strongest tailed beast overall. The argument of kurama being as strong as at least 5 biju is supported by him creating a tailed beast ball able to cancel out a combined tailed beast ball empowered by 5 tailed beast.